# ASP Object required

Tags: asp-classic

I have the error in Classic ASP:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
Object required: 'SqlStatement'
/Data/Database.asp, line 186
```

The line 186 is: `SqlStatement.CommandText = sql`.

Here is my code:

```vbs
Dim Db, SqlStatement, RS
Set Db = Nothing
Set SqlStatement = Nothing
Set RS = Nothing

' Initialize the database once
Private Sub SqlInitDb()
    If isNull(Db) Or varType(Db) = vbEmpty Or IsObject(Db) = False Then
        ' Create database connection object
        Set Db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        ' Set connection timeout
        Db.ConnectionTimeout = Session("ConnectionTimeout")
        ' Set command timeout
        Db.CommandTimeout = Session("CommandTimeout")
        ' Open database
        Db.Open Session("ConnectionString")
    End If

    If isNull(SqlStatement) Or varType(SqlStatement) = vbEmpty Or IsObject(SqlStatement) = False Then
        ' Create a sql statement
        Set SqlStatement = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        ' Set opened database as active connection for the SQL statement
        SqlStatement.ActiveConnection = Db
    End If
End Sub

' Close the database if it is not closed
Private Sub SqlClose()
    If Not isNull(SqlStatement) And varType(SqlStatement) <> vbEmpty And IsObject(SqlStatement) = True Then
        SqlStatement.ActiveConnection.Close
    End If

    Set SqlStatement = Nothing

    If Not isNull(Db) And varType(Db) <> vbEmpty And IsObject(Db) = True Then
        For Each objErr In Db.Errors
          response.write("<p>")
          response.write("Description: ")
          response.write(objErr.Description & "<br>")
          response.write("Help context: ")
          response.write(objErr.HelpContext & "<br>")
          response.write("Help file: ")
          response.write(objErr.HelpFile & "<br>")
          response.write("Native error: ")
          response.write(objErr.NativeError & "<br>")
          response.write("Error number: ")
          response.write(objErr.Number & "<br>")
          response.write("Error source: ")
          response.write(objErr.Source & "<br>")
          response.write("SQL state: ")
          response.write(objErr.SQLState & "<br>")
          response.write("</p>")
        Next
        Db.Close()
        Set Db = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

' Insert a user to the database
Public Function InsertUser(ByVal userObj)
    If isNull(userObject) Or varType(userObject) = vbEmpty Then
        InsertUser = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    Call SqlInitDb()
    Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Dim sql
    sql = "INSERT INTO users(Firstname,Surname) VALUES ('"&userObj.getFirstname()&"','"&userObj.getSurname()&"')"
    SqlStatement.CommandText = sql
    SqlStatement.CommandType = 1

    ' Run the insert statement
    SqlStatement.Execute
    InsertUser = Err.Number
    Call SqlClose()
End Function
```

SqlStatement is clearly an object so I don't understand.

Thanks

Comment: No it's classic ASP. What makes you think it is ASP.NET?

Comment: try checking for `Nothing` too, in init method :`If isNull(SqlStatement) Or (varType(SqlStatement) = vbEmpty) Or (IsObject(SqlStatement) = False) or (SqlStatement is Nothing) Then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript got many ways to define variable as empty, null, nothing and more.

The problem you stumbled into is that *Nothing* is actually an object. It's not null, it's not empty and it's totally valid object, which just happens to be of special kind.

Thus, your condition always failed, returning False even though the variable was Nothing.

To solve this, use the only proper way in VBScript to check for that special value:

```vbs
If SqlStatement Is Nothing Then
    ' Create a sql statement
    Set SqlStatement = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    ' Set opened database as active connection for the SQL statement
    SqlStatement.ActiveConnection = Db
End If
```

The only downside is that you must now make sure to initialize the variable as *Nothing*, which you now do, otherwise it will throw error.